# Htaccess redirect single file 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have changed a file name and I want to create a permanent redirect (301).

My .htaccess file is in a subdirectory (http://example.com/js)

I want to redirect http://example.com/js/oldfilename.js

to http://example.com/js/newfilename.js

With this code, the redirect works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^oldfilename.js$ newfilename.js [L]
```

But the URL is not rewritten. When I change `[L]` to `[L,R=301]` the URL is rewritten but is broken. The rewritten URL seems to be the http host (http://example.com) followed by the absolute path to the file in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform an external redirection and specify the base for rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/path/to/files/"
RewriteRule ^oldfilename\.js$ newfilename.js [L,R=301]
```

---

It would however be much easier to simply define an `Alias` in the http host configuration:

```
Alias /path/to/oldfilename.js /path/to/newfilename.js
```

In general you should *always* prefer to place such rules inside the real host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server, often for nothing. They are only provided for situation where one does *not* have access to the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting providers) or if an application needs to write it's own rewriting rules (which is a security nightmare anyway...).